# Update/Refresh DBImage

Tags: delphi

I have a form that displays data from a master and a detail query.  Opening a modal window allows the user to edit data from the detail query.

I want the display of the detail data (in this case, a `TDBImage`) to be updated on the main form when the modal window is closed.  I thought that this was a trivial task, but I cannot make it happen unless I step off the master record and step back.

I have tried all of the following:

```pascal
imgEmployee.Enabled := false;
qEmpPhoto.Close;
with TfrmPhotos.Create(Self) do
begin
  ShowModal;
  Free;
end;
imgEmployee.Enabled := true;
qEmpPhoto.Open;
qEmpPhoto.Refresh;
frmMain.Refresh;
imgEmployee.Refresh;
imgEmployee.Repaint;
```

Clearly it is possible, because the `Next`/`Prior` methods work, but it seems like it should be possible without such hacky shenanigans.

Further experimentation reveals that the failure to update only happens when the first detail record is added.  When there are no details and I add one, when the modal window closes, there is no change.  If there is a detail record and I add a newer one, the `TDBImage` now shows that new image.  An empty result on the detail table is a special case.

Comment: If using FireDac there is `RefreshRecord()` to just reload the current record from the database.  Use it on the detail dataset.

Comment: Alas, I am using uniDAC

Comment: uniDac does have a RefreshRecord method as well, might not be accessible without some work as it is meant to be called internally based off RefreshOptions. (https://docs.devart.com/unidac/devart.dac.tcustomdadataset.refreshrecord().htm).

Comment: Further experimentation reveals that the failure to update only happens when the first detail record is added.  When there are no details and I add one, when the modal window closes, there is no change.  If there is a detail record and I add a newer one, the `TDBImage` now shows that new image.  An empty result on the detail table is a special case.  (question has been updated)